# Use Python Regex to take string starting with a certain word all the way till end of line

Tags: python, regex

Trying to take specific lines from a file that is read and make it a usable variable that is returned.

For some information about the data in the file. The syntax goes like this.

```
A line of text I do not need  
New domain: www.example.com  
Another line that I do not need  
New domain: www.example2.com  
Ect...
```

It reads the file, I've tried the a bunch of variations of the example regex pattern and know I'm close. Other than that It's rather straightforward.

```
data = []
with open('test.txt', 'r') as file: 

    data = (re.findall(r"(?<=New domain:).+$",open('test.txt'), re.M))
return data
```

Happy Path: 
The function reads from test.txt file, looks at only the lines that start with New domain: and only takes the url all the way to the end of the line and puts it into a list.

Errors:
 It just tells me that the pattern syntax is wrong.

Comment: You can try to get rid of the `$` and the `re.M`.

Comment: Also, isn't findall looking for a string there. Does that open return a file handle ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex pattern is fine, but you can't pass a file object to `findall`. Try this instead:

```
data = (re.findall(r"(?<=New domain:).+$", file.read(), re.M))
```

Comment: Ohhhh r is a string wrap. Ok, thanks man. The hardest part for me with regex and data structures is sometimes things have to be quite specific to work.

Comment: Since he's opening the file in the `with` statement, you can just do `file.read()`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the file first before passing it to the `re.findall()` method. You can also simply the regex.

```
def find_domains():
    with open('test.txt', 'r+') as file:
        file_text = file.read()
        data = re.findall("New domain: (.*)", file_text)
    return data
```